# manually revoking an expired access token

Tags: google-oauth-java-client

What is the response when you try to manually revoke an access token which has already expired/been revoked by Google
I am trying to revoke it manually by sending a Https get request to url:
https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/revoke?token={token}